# Nginx rewrite rules for prestashop, how to setup, debug and enable?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, prestashop

I want to change from Apache to Nginx+Php-Fpm for performance reasons. Currently I can see homepage of my website (in test environment) but any friendly url that worked in Apache does not work now.

I have already converted rules to nginx rules but I don't have any way to test it because, every click on some url of the site turns into my browser download the php file!

for example

I click on www.misite.com/autentication and my browser download a php file :-/

Environment Test is

- PHP 5.3.17 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2012 06:45:07)
  Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
- nginx -v
  nginx version: nginx/1.0.15

Here it is my nginx virtual host config:

```
server {
        server_name     site.com www.site.com;
        root            /srv/www/site.com/httpdocs;
        access_log      /srv/www/site.com/log/access.log;
        error_log       /srv/www/site.com/log/error.log;
        rewrite_log on;
        location / {
                index  index.html index.htm index.php;
                rewrite ^/([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1-$2.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z-]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg? break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\.html /product.php?id_product=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]*(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*)+ /category.php?id_category=$1&noredirect=1 break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)\-[a-zA-Z0-9-]* /category.php?id_category=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)__([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /supplier.php?id_supplier=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/([0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /manufacturer.php?id_manufacturer=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/content/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?id_cms=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/content/category/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /cms.php?id_cms_category=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/pagina-no-encuentra$ /404.php break;
rewrite ^/direccion$ /address.php break;
        rewrite ^/direcciones$ /addresses.php break;
        rewrite ^/autenticacion$ /authentication.php break;
        rewrite ^/mas-vendidos$ /best-sales.php break;
        rewrite ^/carro-de-la-compra$ /cart.php break;
        rewrite ^/contactenos$ /contact-form.php break;
        rewrite ^/descuento$ /discount.php break;
        rewrite ^/estado-pedido$ /guest-tracking.php break;
        rewrite ^/historial-de-pedidos$ /history.php break;
        rewrite ^/identidad$ /identity.php break;
        rewrite ^/fabricantes$ /manufacturer.php break;
        rewrite ^/mi-cuenta$ /my-account.php break;
        rewrite ^/nuevos-productos$ /new-products.php break;
        rewrite ^/carrito$ /order.php break;
        rewrite ^/devolucion-de-productos$ /order-follow.php break;
        rewrite ^/pedido-rapido$ /order-opc.php break;
        rewrite ^/vales$ /order-slip.php break;
        rewrite ^/contrasena-olvidado$ /password.php break;
        rewrite ^/promocion$ /prices-drop.php break;
        rewrite ^/buscar$ /search.php break;
        rewrite ^/mapa-del-sitio$ /sitemap.php break;
        rewrite ^/tiendas$ /stores.php break;
        rewrite ^/proveedores$ /supplier.php break;
        error_page 404 = /404.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

Worst problem is I don't have some experience to debug the problem :-/ Very new with Nginx
Any comment will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: PS: In fact, the behaviour is urls like /authentication makes browser tu download a file and urls like /some-product.html gets a 404 error, so, I can confirm rewrites are not working :(

Comment: could you mention which prestashop version it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed my own issue! It was so easy by the way, only was to change the location of the rules

I've moved all rules of

```
location /{
.... rules...
}
```

to

```
server {

...here rules works...

}
```

Then I reload nginx and that's it!

service nginx reload

I hope this can be useful for some desperate guy like me.

Best regards,

Ruben